# >>> or ::v-deep not working in Vue project

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I currently want to replace `/deep/` for `::v-deep` or `>>>` in my Laravel/Vue project because it is deprecated. But the only thing that keeps working is `/deep/` the other options does not seem to work. For example I have this styling in my component:

```
<style scoped>
.v-data-table
  >>>
  tbody
  >>>
  tr:hover:not(.v-data-table__expanded__content) {
  background: #ffffff !important;
}

.v-data-table >>> tr {
  height: 60px;
}
</style>
```

It only works when I use `/deep/`, `>>>` doesn't to anything. I don't know if it has something to do with my used packages or webpack config. I recently updated all my NPM packages, this is my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.3",
    "sass-loader": "7.*",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
},
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
    "secure-ls": "^1.2.6",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.15.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.17",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.7.1"
}
```

And my `webpack.mix.js` config:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .options({
        postCss: [
            require('autoprefixer'),
        ],
    })
```

What am I currently missing that I can't use the new deep selectors? Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

The full component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :disable-sort="true"
    :item-key="itemKey"
    :disable-pagination="true"
    :hide-default-footer="true"
    :search="search"
  >
    <template v-for="slot in Object.keys($scopedSlots)" :slot="slot" slot-scope="scope">
      <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope" />
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BaseDataTable",
  props: {
    headers: Array,
    items: Array,
    itemKey: {
      type: String,
      default: "id"
    },
    search: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.v-data-table
  /deep/
  tbody
  /deep/
  tr:hover:not(.v-data-table__expanded__content) {
  background: #ffffff !important;
}

.v-data-table /deep/ tr {
  height: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you fixed this?

Comment: I haven't been able to fix this unfortunately.. sorry @吴张明

Answer (score 1):

I meet this problem in the Mpvue Or the Uniapp.
I fixed it finally by adding an option. But I am not sure it's suited for Vue projects. You can try it.

```
options: { styleIsolation: 'shared' }, // add this
methods: {
  yourFunc1 () {
  }
}
```